# Gallio Icarus never shows a file tree

Tags: visual-studio-2008, testing

Well I'm trying to run some tests in VS using MbUnit and Gallio. I'm trying to run them through Icarus. I'm simply going through the basic tutorial on the site, and were it says to add "SimpleLibrary.Test.dll", it shows an entire tree. However, mine WONT show a tree. It just shows the one file.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're on the project tab, rather than the test view. Try View -> Test Explorer.